# crashing out while exiting : Android

Tags: android, android-camera

```
   public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;;
PictureCallback rawCallback;
ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
PictureCallback jpegCallback;
private Bitmap bitmap;
TextView colorRGB;
Config config;
String callname;

String callnameRimage;


EditText txtData, PatientInfo,PatientAge;


ImageView imageView = null;
ImageView imageView2 = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


   Button buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
   Button buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);
   Button buttonCapturePreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capturepreview);
   Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton); 
   Button flipButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flip);


    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);





    rawCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
    {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
         {

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Image");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            name = s.toString() + ".jpg";

            File output = new File(imagesFolder, name);
            callname = "/sdcard/Asw/Raw Image/" + name;

            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {

                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");




    buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!previewing)
            {
                camera = Camera.open(0);
                if (camera != null)
                {

                    try {

                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        camera.startPreview();
                        previewing = true;

                        } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                        {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }else txtData.setText("null");
            }
        }});



    buttonCapturePreview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            captureImage();
        }


    });


    buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            if(camera != null && previewing)
            {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;

                previewing = false;
            }
        }});
     }

private void captureImage() 
{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
}

private void displayimages()
{

    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    callnameRimage = "/sdcard/Asw/Raw Image/" + name;
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callnameRimage);

    imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);



       Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
         finish();  
         Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidCamera.this, AndroidCamera.class);
         startActivity(intent);

        }
        });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_camera, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) 
{}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}
```

}

The program is running perfect. but when i exit from the application, it get crashes out.i have added the logcat error. I thinks something wrong is goin in surface destroyed. but am not able to identify it. Can anyone please suggest a way to get solve it out.

```
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806): java.lang.NullPointerException
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at com.example.imaging.AndroidCamera.surfaceDestroyed(AndroidCamera.java:512)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:1099)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:244)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:5843)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:990)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2467)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 12-16 12:24:54.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3806):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you pressing `buttonStopCameraPreview` before exiting?

Comment: no....i want to exit the application safely even if i didnt press it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if(camera != null){
          camera.stopPreview();
          camera.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your LogCat clearly shows where the problem is - line 512 of your file, method `surfaceDestroyed`. So there is some problem with how you release the camera - to the documentation then!

Taken from here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

`Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).`

So now we need to know when does surfaceDestroyed occur in reference to onPause - see the accepted answer here : [When does surfaceDestroyed() occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606685/when-does-surfacedestroyed-occur)

Solution : move your code to onPause.